# Angular throwing Material errors after upgrading to version 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-upgrade

I've updated the Angular project from v8 to v9 and followed all the required updates but running `ng serve` throws material errors. I've imported all material components individually instead of importing directly from `@angular/material` and included all these in separate file `material.module.ts`. This file is imported in `app.module.ts` but still Angular is not detecting any material components and **throwing below errors:**

[image]

**Below are the dependencies:** 
[image]

**Note:**
*I've tried almost all available solutions and asking this question after no success.*

Answer (score 3):

The real problem with your project is **included all these in separate file material.module.ts** . From Angular 9+, you should explicitly declare which Material Modules are imported instead of creating **one shared module**. I have resolved a problem before by refactoring most of own modules. Step by step here is:

1. Remove `Shared Material Module`
2. Run to print out all own modules have problem
3. Declare explicitly Material Module which it has associated with.

```js
@NgModule({
   imports: [
      MatToolbarModule
   ]
})
export class OwnModule { }
```

I know it is very painful but we don't have any choice to upgrade Angular 9+.

Comment: I had the same problem two months before.
And I fixed just adding my own Module and imported then in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: @Johnathan You mean I have to import modules in components instead of app.module ?

Comment: Correct, you should import Material Modules as much as you used in your own module instead of declaring them in app.module or shared module. I don't know how your project's structure is, but new practice is above. Anw, in app.module, if you have any child component which is using Material, you should import as well.

Comment: But the docs said:   Instead of importing from @angular/material, you should import deeply from the specific component. E.g. @angular/material/button.

They don't mention anywhere that don't import in app.module instead import in component.

Importing in every component is not easy job to do.

Comment: Not component, declare it in your module level. That's the reason why I said it is very painful. I know it is very hard to do this job but I tried many times and research the behind reason. It is belonging to new Ivy. You should import in any module which has `declerations` components using Material Modules. Back to app.module.ts, it is just one module. And you have two declaration components which are NavComponent and HeaderComponent. They are using MatToolbarModule so you must declare in `imports` this module.